# Error: illegal start of expression y error: ';' '(' expected en jcreator

Tags: java, jcreator

No sé porqué me da muchos errores en la línea 6.
Me sale que:

> error: ')' expected error:  expected error: ';' expected

y varios iguales

```
public class Verify
{

    public static void main (String[] args)    
    {
        int[] a =(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        System.out.println (repetido (a));
    }
    
    public static boolean repetido(int[] array)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<array.lenght; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<array.lenght; j++)
            {
                if(i!=j && array[i]==array[j])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema en la linea 5 el array puede ser iniciado de

```java
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,  7,8, 9};
```

código completo

```java
class Verify {

    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,  7,8, 9};
        System.out.println (repetido (a));
    }

    public static boolean repetido(int[] array)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++)
            {
                if(i!=j && array[i]==array[j])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```